# Context menu in SwiftUI with nested views

Tags: swiftui, contextmenu

Looks like there's a problem  when  using  the .contextMenu view modifier with nested views.

Here's sample code  showing  the problem:

```
import SwiftUI

enum SampleEnum: String, CaseIterable {
  case one, two, three, four
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Form {
      Section {
        VStack  {
          HStack  {
            ForEach(SampleEnum.allCases, id:\.self) { id in
              Text(id.rawValue)
                .contextMenu {
                  Button {
                    print("Change country setting")
                  } label: {
                    Label("Choose Country", systemImage: "globe")
                  }
                }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

Here's the result:
[image]

So, it doesn't appear that a context menu can be performed on a single Text view since  the entire section/stack is selected.

Is there any way to get the contextMenu to work on an individual Text view in such a  nested layout?

Comment: Likely to do with the form. Try a Vstack and see if there is a difference

Comment: `.contextMenu` is deprecated

Comment: @eXCore Only the version of .contextMenu that takes a ContextMenu value is deprecated.

Comment: @LukeRedpath Yeah, my bad, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this workaround, I changed `contextMenu` to `Menu()` and passed your `Text()` as its param, made each text has its own menu as you wanted and prints each ID correctly as a proof that each action is independent to each Text()

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                VStack  {
                    HStack  {
                        ForEach(SampleEnum.allCases, id:\.self) { id in
                            Menu("\(Text(id.rawValue))") {
                                Button {
                                    print("Change country setting")
                                    print(id)
                                } label: {
                                    Label("Choose Country", systemImage: "globe")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Recording]

Comment: Thanks!  My example was a simpler version of  what  my app needs but a simple test in the actual app looks promising.

Comment: @Phantom59 glad it helped :)